# Use of $ sign in scala template?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Please explain why the $ is used in the below code:

```
 <ul>
  @for(p <- products) {
    <li>@p.getName() ($@p.getPrice())</li>
  } 
 </ul>
```

Also it would be great if you can suggest some good tutorial to master scala template..`Play 2.0 uses scala template instead of groovy template.

Comment: The $ confused me as well :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dollar sign here is just part of the HTML being outputted, so the price displays as `$100` for example. It is not doing anything special.
It is next to the @ symbol, so there is no space when the HTML is outputted.

If you are used to Play 1.x, this is equivalent of doing

```
$(${p.getPrice()})
```

Comment: so it can be just `<li>@p.getName() (USD @p.getPrice())</li>` or something else

Comment: @shomiknaik: Best tutorials are placed in the samples and docs. You will not find better resources.